# Summarize the lowest values in a Dataframe?

Tags: r, summarize

My data frame looks like this:

```
View(df)
Product     Value
  a           2
  b           4 
  c           3
  d           10
  e           15
  f           5
  g           6
  h           4
  i           50
  j           20
  k           35
  l           25
  m           4
  n           6
  o           30
  p           4
  q           40
  r           5
  s           3
  t           40
```

I want to find the 9 most expensive products and summaries the rest. It should look like this:

```
Product     Value 
  d           10
  e           15
  i           50
  j           20
  k           35
  l           25
  o           30
  q           40
  t           40
 rest         46
```

Rest is the sum of the other 11 products. 
I tried it with `summaries`, but it didn't work:

```
new <- df %>%
  group_by(Product)%>%
summarise((Value > 10) = sum(Value)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::row_number` to effectively rank the observations after using `arrange` to order the data by `Value`. Then, we augment the `Product` column so that any values that aren't in the top 9 are coded as `Rest`. Finally, we group by the updated `Product` and take the sum using `summarise`

```
dat %>%
    arrange(desc(Value)) %>%
    mutate(RowNum = row_number(),
           Product = ifelse(RowNum <= 9, Product, 'Rest')) %>%
    group_by(Product) %>%
    summarise(Value = sum(Value))

# A tibble: 10 × 2
   Product Value
     <chr> <int>
1        d    10
2        e    15
3        i    50
4        j    20
5        k    35
6        l    25
7        o    30
8        q    40
9     Rest    46
10       t    40
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Product = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"
), Value = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 15L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 50L, 20L, 35L, 
25L, 4L, 6L, 30L, 4L, 40L, 5L, 3L, 40L)), .Names = c("Product", 
"Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `dplyr` would be to create the outcome with `do`. The code becomes a bit hard to read since you need to use `.$`, yet you can avoid `ifelse/if_else`. After arranging the order by `Value`, you can create two vectors. One with the first nine product names and "rest". The other with the first nine values and the sum of the value of the other values. You directly create a data frame using `do`.

```
df %>%
arrange(desc(Value)) %>%
do(data.frame(Product = c(as.character(.$Product[1:9]), "Rest"),
              Value = c(.$Value[1:9], sum(.$Value[10:length(.$Value)]))))

#   Product Value
#1        i    50
#2        q    40
#3        t    40
#4        k    35
#5        o    30
#6        l    25
#7        j    20
#8        e    15
#9        d    10
#10    Rest    46
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, i1 := .I][order(desc(Value))
          ][-(seq_len(9)), Product := 'rest'
           ][, .(Value = sum(Value), i1=i1[1L]), Product
           ][order(Product=='rest', i1)][, i1 := NULL][]
#    Product Value
#1:       d    10
#2:       e    15
#3:       i    50
#4:       j    20
#5:       k    35
#6:       l    25
#7:       o    30
#8:       q    40
#9:       t    40
#10:   rest    46
```